# Display Cell in a Table Form

Tags: octave

I am wondering If it is possible to display Cell in a Table Form while using Octave. It would be easier for me to obtain information of the Cell. If it were displayed in a single column, I have to scroll down all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell array default display looks kinda complicated:

```
octave> a = {"foo", "bar", "qux"; "baz", "nof", "zot"}
a = 
{
  [1,1] = foo
  [2,1] = baz
  [1,2] = bar
  [2,2] = nof
  [1,3] = qux
  [2,3] = zot
}
```

It would be much nicer to see something such as:

```
octave> a = {"foo", "bar", "qux"; "baz", "nof", "zot"}
a(1:2, 1:3) = 
{
  "foo"    "bar"    "qux"
  "baz"    "nof"    "zot"
}
```

However, a cell array can have anything inside each of its cells. This includes other cell arrays, structs, and very long lines with linebreaks. Because of this, a sensible display of a cell array is very dependent on its contents and what the user is interested on taking from them.

What this means, is that it is up to the user to create a function that displays what he wants.  I will provide an example that is useful for the case above, which is the most common case, i.e., a 2 dimensional cell array of short one-line strings. The solution is to create a format for printf on the fly from the longest string on each column like so:

```
octave> a = {"foobar", "bar", "qux"; "baz", "nofnot", "zotr"};
octave> col_width = max (cellfun (@numel, a)) +4
col_width =

   10   10    8

octave> row_template= [sprintf("%%%is", col_width) "\n"]
row_template = %10s%10s%8s

octave> printf (row_template, a'{:})
    foobar       bar     qux
       baz    nofnot    zotr
```

Or on a single line:

```
octave> printf ([sprintf("%%%is", max (cellfun (@numel, a))+4) "\n"], a'{:})
    foobar       bar     qux
       baz    nofnot    zotr
```

More complex cell arrays, with a more complex but organized structure, can instead make use of Octave's [dataframe](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/index.html).  For example:

```
octave> pkg load dataframe
octave> C = {"Patient Name", "Volume", "Quality", "Owner"; "Joe", 200, .95, "MR"; "Dana", 186, .93, "MR"; "Cassidy", 197, .96, "SP"};
octave> dataframe (C)
ans = dataframe with 3 rows and 4 columns
_1 Patient_Name Volume Quality Owner     
Nr         char double  double  char     
 1          Joe    200 0.95000    MR     
 2         Dana    186 0.93000    MR     
 3      Cassidy    197 0.96000    SP
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Now I will need to install dataframe package, since the 1. methode ends up quite messy, but it was a smart way of thinking.

Comment: since my server has no access to internet, I have to install "dataframe" manually. I am working on that.

Comment: I could transform it to dataframe. But while displaying it in 45 columns I got the following http://i61.tinypic.com/fvdb1k.png. Could I change the setting of width of the dataframe display?

Comment: @KenStark the width is usually the width of your terminal. Your best choice to chnage that, is to pick a pager and configure it as you want. But that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tablicious package to display information in tabular form.

installation:

```
pkg install https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious/releases/download/v0.3.5/tablicious-0.3.5.tar.gz;
```

To answer the question:

you can use a method called cell2table from tablicious package to convert cell to table.

```
    C =
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [2,1] = 2
  [3,1] = 3
  [4,1] = 4
  [5,1] = 5
  [1,2] = Adam
  [2,2] = Jane
  [3,2] = Amit
  [4,2] = Leena
  [5,2] = Desh
  [1,3] = 23
  [2,3] = 34
  [3,3] = 22
  [4,3] = 45
  [5,3] = 100
  [1,4] = M
  [2,4] = F
  [3,4] = M
  [4,4] = F
  [5,4] = M
}

out = cell2table(C)
prettyprint(out)
```

Output:

```
Ԁout =
table: 5 rows x 4 variables
  VariableNames: Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4
------------------------------
| Var1 | Var2  | Var3 | Var4 |
------------------------------
| 1    | Adam  | 23   | M    |
| 2    | Jane  | 34   | F    |
| 3    | Amit  | 22   | M    |
| 4    | Leena | 45   | F    |
| 5    | Desh  | 100  | M    |
------------------------------
>>
```

Link to the official documentation:
https://tablicious.janklab.net/user-guide/tablicious.pdf